# How to compile Go program consisting of multiple files?

Tags: go, build, compiler-errors

I have a small program that consists of three files, all belonging to the same package (main). But when I do `go build main.go` the build doesn't succeed. When it was just one file (`main.go`), everything worked fine.

Now that I took some effort to separate the code, it looks like the compiler is unable to find the stuff that was taken out of `main.go` and put into these two other files (that reside in the same directory as the main.go). Which results in `undefined 'type'` errors.

How to compile this program that consists of multiple files?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

#### New Way (*Recommended*):

[Please take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61793820/115363).

#### Old Way:

Supposing you're writing a program called myprog :

Put all your files in a directory like this

```
myproject/go/src/myprog/xxx.go
```

Then add `myproject/go` to GOPATH

And run

```
go install myprog
```

This way you'll be able to add other packages and programs in myproject/go/src if you want.

Reference : http://golang.org/doc/code.html

(this doc is always missed by newcomers, and often ill-understood at first. It should receive the greatest attention of the Go team IMO)

Comment: why not get rid of the /go/ and just do myproject/src?

Comment: also, I assume "go install myprog" writes the project source into the $GOPATH location somehow? Is that right? if so, would be nice to have that explanation as part of the answer as well

Comment: @AlexanderMills Only small projects are using just one technology.

Comment: @DenysSéguret not sure I agree with that, but anyway this is for simple projects, you could just drop the go part - people might assume that the go thing is necessary and it's not. You tell me, which is simpler, the go or the no-go? :)

Comment: I still don't understand why this folder structure?

Answer (score 71):

When you separate code from `main.go` into for example `more.go`, you simply pass that file to `go build`/`go run`/`go install` as well.

So if you previously ran

```
go build main.go
```

you now simply

```
go build main.go more.go
```

---

As further information:

```
go build --help
```

states:

> If the arguments are a list of .go files,
>   build treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package.

---

Notice that `go build` and `go install` differ from `go run` in that the first two state to expect *package names* as arguments, while the latter expects *go files*. However, the first two will also accept go files as go install does.

If you are wondering: build will just `build` the packages/files, `install` will produce object and binary files in your GOPATH, and `run` will compile and run your program.

Comment: If you don't want to keep adding more and more files, use regex, with:
 go run *.go

Comment: ok thanks, does Go always write only one executable file out? It doesn't keep the executable files separated (like in Java)?

Comment: @AlexanderMills because of windows, i think, use nix. or mingw at least.

Comment: yeah I was using MacOS, but maybe it's Bash version 3 that is fuckin' up, I should upgrade to Bash 4.

Answer (score 58):

Since Go 1.11+, GOPATH is no longer recommended, the new way is using Go Modules.

#### Say you're writing a program called `simple`:

1. Create a directory:

   ```sh
   mkdir simple
   cd simple
   ```
2. Create a new module:

   ```sh
   go mod init github.com/username/simple
   # Here, the module name is: github.com/username/simple.
   # You're free to choose any module name.
   # It doesn't matter as long as it's unique.
   # It's better to be a URL: so it can be go-gettable.
   ```
3. Put all your files in that directory.
4. Finally, run:

   ```sh
   go run .
   ```
5. Alternatively, you can create an executable program by building it:

   ```sh
   go build .

   # then:
   ./simple     # if you're on xnix

   # or, just:
   simple       # if you're on Windows
   ```

For more information, you may read [this](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

> Go has included support for versioned modules as proposed here since 1.11. The initial prototype vgo was announced in February 2018. In July 2018, versioned modules landed in the main Go repository.
>   In Go 1.14, module support is considered ready for production use, and all users are encouraged to migrate to modules from other dependency management systems.

Comment: I'm not writing a simple program, lets say i have a big project with multiple packages. How do I create an executable for that? Do I have to go to each package and run go build?

Comment: Whether you're creating an extensive program or not, provide a single entry point to it and compile your program through that.

Comment: All go files need to have the same package.

Comment: All Go files in the same package should have the same package declaration except test files.

Answer (score 34):

You could also just run

```
go build
```

in your project folder myproject/go/src/myprog

Then you can just type

```
./myprog
```

to run your app

Comment: the output is a go object, not an executable.

Comment: @user2284570 just add ```chmod +x``` permission for that file to run it

Answer (score 14):

It depends on your project structure. But most straightforward is:

```
go build -o ./myproject ./...
```

then run `./myproject`.

Suppose your project structure looks like this

```
- hello
|- main.go
```

then you just go to the project directory and run

```
go build -o ./myproject
```

then run `./myproject` on shell.

or

```
# most easiest; builds and run simultaneously
go run main.go
```

suppose your main file is nested into a sub-directory like a `cmd`

```
- hello
|- cmd
 |- main.go
```

then you will run

```
go run cmd/main.go
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
go build *.go 
go run *.go
```

both will work also you may use

```
go build .
go run .
```

Answer (score 3):

Yup! That's very straight forward and that's where the package strategy comes into play. there are three ways to my knowledge.
folder structure:

```
GOPATH/src/
      github.com/
      abc/
      myproject/
            adapter/
                main.go
                pkg1
                pkg2
```

warning: adapter can contain package main only and sun directories

1. navigate to "adapter" folder. Run:

```
    go build main.go
```

2. navigate to "adapter" folder. Run:

```
    go build main.go
```

3. navigate to GOPATH/src
   recognize relative path to package main, here "myproject/adapter". Run:

```
    go build myproject/adapter
```

**exe file will be created at the directory you are currently at.**