# What's the correct organisation for Go projects using Git (or any VCS)?

Tags: git, go

My GOPATH is `/Users/joe/go`. I am working on a project called `myproj`, which is a package called `myproj`.

If I want to be able to write `import "myproj"` then the directory structure I need is:

```
$GOPATH/src/myproj/myproj.go
$GOPATH/src/myproj/myproj_test.go
...
```

However, I can't seem to make this fit with Git. If I look at an [example package from Google](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/?repo=example) I see the following format:

```
go.example/hello/hello.go
go.example/LICENSE
```

Where `go.example` is the name of the repo.

So the actual package directories are found *inside* the repository. If I put the contents of this repository in a directory on my $GOPATH, e.g.

```
$GOPATH/src/go.example/hello/hello.go
$GOPATH/src/go.example/LICENSE
```

then I will have to type `import "go.example/hello"` rather than `import "hello"`.

Coming back to my project, I need to package this up in a Git repository then I need a container directory. So my current file structure is:

```
$GOPATH/src/myproj                        # The dir for the git repo
$GOPATH/src/myproj/.git
$GOPATH/src/myproj/LICENSE                # Files in the base of the repo
$GOPATH/src/myproj/myproj/myproj.go       # Package files in package dir
$GOPATH/src/myproj/myproj/myproj_test.go
```

I need the outer `myproj` directory to bound the git repository and I need the inner one to be the package directory. The upshot is that I need to type `import "myproj/myproj"` rather than `import "myproj"`.

How do I fix this? Do I have to add multiple $GOPATHS, one for each project I'm developing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you need to add multiple entries to your GOPATH (separated as defined by your platform). Please read my detailled answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838469/how-to-compile-go-program-consisting-of-multiple-files)

Comment: IIUC: No, I don't think a GOPATH entry for every package is advisable at all.

Comment: Not for each package but for each project (at least the ones who aren't exposed in github (or similar) with a defined and fixed URL).

Comment: @Joe as you can see, there is more than one way to do it. Two of them work very well. Jnml one's seems simpler (never change GOPATH). Mine seems to me (but I may be wrong) cleaner for projects involving much more than Go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off:

> Do I have to add multiple `$GOPATH`s, one for each project I'm developing?

**No, you don’t need multiple `$GOPATH`s at all.**

They are a tool for managing your (potentially several) projects. When you set up a new project environment which you already know will have some dependencies - potentially unique to that project, or which should be similiar to other peoples setups, you create a new project folder and set it as the `GOPATH`. That way, you can also use (= check out) specific versions of a library for that project, while using other versions for your other projects in other project folders (= `GOPATH`s).

As for your path issue: Go follows a generic paradigm of `author/project` (or `organization/project`). This will prevent naming clashes when several people, authors and organizations, start projects with the same names. (The author may then use sub-folders, sub-projects in “his” folder as well ofc.)

If you are aware of this and *still* want to use only `myproj` as your package path, **there is no problem in creating the git repository in that folder** - in contrary to the example package you linked to.

> Coming back to my project, I need to package this up in a Git repository then I need a container directory.

What makes you think so then? Go does not need it. Git does neither.

So the following will work:

```
/src/myproj/.git
/src/myproj/myproj.go
```

While it is not the encouraged practice, **you can put the repository into your `myproj` folder**.

---

I tested this as follows:

```
FOLDER
FOLDER/src
FOLDER/src/myproj
FOLDER/src/myproj/myproj.go
FOLDER/src/mainproj
FOLDER/src/mainproj/main.go
```

With `folder/src/myproj/myproj.go`

```
package myproj

type My struct {
    I int
}
```

and `folder/src/mainproj/main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "myproj"
)

func main() {
    my := myproj.My{7}
    fmt.Printf("Works! %v", my.I)
}
```

Running

```
cd FOLDER
set GOPATH=FOLDER
go run src/mainproj/main.go
```

will output:

```
Works! 7
```

Now, if you `git init` in the folder `FOLDER/src/myproj`, that does not matter to Go itself at all.

Answer (score 2):

The usual setup goes like this:

$GOPATH, in the first approximation needs only one path, your example `/Users/joe/go/` is just fine. Now you have a github repository `myproj` seen at `http://github.com/joe/myproj`. The import statement for this package should be

```
import "github.com/joe/myproj"
```

Looking back at your (single valued) $GOPATH, the go tool will look for your package at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/joe/myproj` and that's the "local" root of your "external" github repository with files myproj.go, etc.go, ... inside.

Without these conventions there will be namespace clashes with Jack's (and Alice's and Bob's) project(s) accidentally called also `myproj`, so I recommend to get used to this right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You'll naturally import multiple packages :

- the standard ones
- a few ones you'll download using `go get`
- a few ones in your project
- a few ones in other projects

The simplest is to choose a directory where you'll `go get` all the external packages (mysql driver for example) and add your project directories to GOPATH.

For example, here's my (simplified) GOPATH :

```
export GOPATH=/home/dys/dev/go:/home/dys/dev/Chrall/go:/home/dys/dev/braldop/go:/home/dys/dev/lg/go
```

I put all the external libraries obtained using `go get` in `/home/dys/dev/go` and Chrall, braldop and lg are 3 of my projects.

In each one of those 3 projects, I have packages and commands. For example :

```
/home/dys/dev/lg/go/src/pkg1/xxx.go
/home/dys/dev/lg/go/src/pkg2/xxx.go
/home/dys/dev/lg/go/src/prog1/xxx.go
```

etc.

All packages are found via GOPATH.

For example when I use a driver mysql, in one of those xxx.go :

```
import (
"database/sql"
_ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
)
```

The driver has been installed in /home/dys/dev/go using

```
go get github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv
```

**Reference :** http://golang.org/doc/code.html

> GOPATH=/home/user/ext:/home/user/mygo
>
> (On a Windows system use
>   semicolons as the path separator instead of colons.)
>
> Each path in the list (in this case /home/user/ext or /home/user/mygo)
>   specifies the location of a workspace. A workspace contains Go source
>   files and their associated package objects, and command executables.

Comment: I have a lot of published packages, I use a lot of other's packages, I work on unpublished-yet and publishing-not-intended packages, I have my hobby projects and throw away code, everything living in peace w/ each other - and my $GOPATH is, and always was, `$HOME`.

Comment: I too have published packages and other people's packages. But the difference may be that in most of my projects the Go part is only a small part and I really want the Go directory to be with the rest of my project. Not sure if it would work very well your way (but if your opinion differs on this point this is interesting).