# Creating an AWS serverless lambda project in Golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda, makefile, build, serverless

I'm trying to build an API in Golang leveraging Serverless and AWS,
I have a folder we'll call apiOne, in that folder I have four files

- main.go
- wf.go
- wi.go
- apiTranslator.go

In my main.go file, I call functions from the wf.go & wi.go files.

- GetWFForecasts
- GetWSForecasts

My serverless.yml file has one function that calls the main.go file

```
  forecasts:
    handler: bin/forecasts
    name: ${self:custom.stackPrefix}-forecasts
    package:
      include:
        - 'src/*'
    description: "Test For API"
    memorySize: 256
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: /forecasts
          method: get
```

I have a Makefile so that it builds for the serverless function

`env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/forecasts src/main.go`

but when I run `make` I get the following error

```
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/forecasts src/main.go
# command-line-arguments
src/main.go:58:24: undefined: GetWFForecasts
src/main.go:59:22: undefined: GetWSForecasts
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I've been fighting with this for a few days now, I have some experience working with AWS serverless using Python but I've been fighting to get the working with Go. I've researched a ton and haven't found anything to help. This isn't simply a "how to compile in go" question, I'm trying to figure out how to use the compiled program in a lambda function. Any advice regarding this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile Go program consisting of multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838469/how-to-compile-go-program-consisting-of-multiple-files) (from [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)  "If the arguments to build are a list of .go files from a single directory, build treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package.")

Comment: That definitely helps point me in the right direction. I appreciate the links!

Comment: Note re your edit; your specific question was about the error and  that should be fixed with something like `env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/forecasts src/`. If you have further questions you should create a new question (but remember that requests for general advice are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here)).